# Generate an array of unique N random numbers which if all numbers summed up equal to N

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Assume that N = 3, I want to make a function to generate 3 unique random numbers which if all numbers summed up will equal to 3. For example:

```
numbers = [1, 0, 2]
numbers = [2, -4, 5]
```

I already have my own solution in JavaScript below:

```
let i = 0;
let arr = []

function getRandomInt(number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(number*2)) - number;
}

function generateArray(i, arr, number) {
  let lastIndex = number-1;

  while (i < lastIndex) {
    let randomNumber = getRandomInt(number);
    if (arr.indexOf(randomNumber) > -1) {
      continue;
    } else {
      arr[i] = randomNumber;
    }
    i++;
  }

  let summed = arr.reduce((a, b) => a+b);
  let lastNumber = number - summed;
  if (arr.indexOf(lastNumber) > -1) {
    return generateArray(lastIndex-1, arr, number);
  } else {
    arr[lastIndex] = lastNumber;
    return arr;
  }
}
```

But I still have a problem with the last index that tends to deviate quite a lot. For example with N = 10, I could have a result like this one below:

```
numbers = [2, -1, 3, 4, -4, 0, -5, -8, -6, 15]
```

I wonder if you guys have a much better solution with also a better performance. Thank you!

Comment: This question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. It should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think it's a fine question here - codereview doesn't accept code that needs debugging (like this one), and OP sounds like he's asking for an entirely new (better) algorithm for the problem, which also sounds too broad for codereview.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, for all the reasons you cite, it definitely belongs on code review. It's way too broad for SO and isn't really asking any specific question.

Comment: This question is fine. I don't support any more closing votes.

Comment: Just to clarify Insan, are you saying that when N = 10 all the values of the array should add up to 10?

Comment: `numbers = [2, -4, 1]` This sums to -1, not to 3?

Comment: what is the wanted range of the random numbers?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm new here and this is my first question. Please let me know if I did something wrong, cheers..

Comment: @Geuis yes, if N = 10, then the generated array with unique random numbers should add up to 10

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm sorry, my bad, I already edit that one, thank you..

Comment: @NinaScholz actually this is a challenge/test from a company, and they didn't explained clearly about the range

Comment: @InsanJati One thing that isn't clear from your question is if values are allowed to be repeated or not. For example, can the solution array look something like `[0, -2, -2, 4, 5]` etc.

Comment: @Geuis Well, he did say `unique N random numbers` in the title

Comment: @Geuis it's not allowed, had to be a unique numbers

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** (I thought about this some more, and think I found an even better way, described below)

Here's what I came up with. This makes the list appear more random, and while there may be a few elements that deviate more than others, but the elements that do could be from any index. It only requires one small change.

You have:

```
let randomNumber = getRandomInt(number);
```

Replace this with:

```
let randomNumber = getRandomInt(number) + i - currentSum;
```

where `currentSum` is just a rolling sum of the array, and `i` is an incrementing variable that starts at zero and increments one every pass through, both of which you would update in the else block of the while loop. (In other words, this would replace the `summed` variable you have as this would keep track of the sum as the array is generating random numbers). What this change aims to do is to normalize the random number to not have the sum go to far from the what the rolling some is *supposed* to be around. To sum *n* numbers to add to *n*, the 'trivial' solution would be to have every number be 1 (i.e. the rolling sum is just the index of the array). What the above code change does is create a random number that generates random numbers around the *expected* rolling sum I just described. Thus, if I were to run the code a million times, the average value of every value in the array would be 1, which is perfect with regards to wanting a list as you described. I tested this method in Java real quick and it seems to do what you want, so I hope this 'quick fix' helps.

Another idea (I did not test this one though) to further reduce deviation would be to, in addition to the above change, make the `generateRandomInt()` function generate numbers in a smaller bound, as right now this function generates numbers with a range of `2 * number`, which could produce bigger numbers than you want.

Here are a few test arrays I got when I ran my the changed code (with `number = 10`):

```
[-3, 10, 0, -4, -1, 6, -5, 5, -7, 9]
[-6, -2, 4, 6, -8, 8, 3, -4, 7, 2]
[-2, 4, -10, 1, 6, 13, -3, -6, 12, -5]
```

I hope you get the idea of this; hope this helps!

P.S. I believe the code you posted should have the `i++` command inside the else block, as otherwise you might not fill up the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet that first fills an array with N unique numbers in a range between -N and N.

Then replaces the last value in the array so that the total = N.

When that recalculated final value is already part of in the array, then the function recurses.
To avoid that the last value isn't unique.
And it also recurses when that final value deviates to much.

```js
function getArrayRandomNumbersInRange(min, max, N) {
   let arr = [];

   while(arr.length < N){
      let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      if(arr.indexOf(num) > -1) continue;
      arr[arr.length] = num;
   }
   let total = arr.reduce(function(accum, val) {return accum + val});
   let lastElem =  arr[arr.length-1] - total + N;
   if(lastElem < min || lastElem > max || (total !== N && arr.indexOf(lastElem) > -1)) {
          //console.log(lastElem + ' -> recurse');
          arr = [];
          return getArrayRandomNumbersInRange(min, max, N);
   }
   arr[arr.length-1] = lastElem;
   return arr;
}

function getArrayRandomNumbers(N){
   return getArrayRandomNumbersInRange(-N, N, N);
}

function sumArray(arr){
   return arr.reduce(function(accum, val) {return accum + val})
}

let randomUniqueArray = getArrayRandomNumbers(5);

console.log("Total:\t" + sumArray(randomUniqueArray));
console.log(randomUniqueArray);
```